# Moto G5 Plus Xt1687 failed to validate recovery image. Can't reboot, can't go to recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, motorola-moto-g5

Something really weird happened to my 6-month old Moto G5 plus. I had an android update, I downloaded the update and during setup, the phone suddenly froze. I was not able to turn it on, so I decided to use recovery mode, and I can't. It reads: "failed to validate recovery image". So I took it to technicians. 4 of them. They all failed, because once they download the OS onto their computers, they cannot install it on my phone. I'm in the US until Wednesday and I need to solve this problem before I get back to Argentina, as I will need my phone to get around the airport and stuff. Is my phone dead for good? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: `I had an android update, I downloaded the update and during setup, the phone suddenly froze` If installed in background, after completion it will ask to reboot. Is something happened during download? or installing?

Comment: All I know is that technicians downloaded the phone OS in their computers and then were unable to pass it to my phone. My phone by itself cannot reboot / go to factory mode because of the error I mentioned on the post (failed to validate recovery image). I don't really know what you mean by "background". I am really ignorant over android and mobile devices in general.

Comment: When an update notification arrives, firstly device will download it(downloads in background ). And then asks you to install. Some devices goto recovery mode for installation. But, in moto, you can install while you're using the phone. That's I have mentioned as background installation. And, I need to know whether anything happened during installation.